# Rails ActiveRecord SQL Queries out of order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm implementing a `sync` method in my rails app, but my SQL queries are being executed in the wrong order, messing up the sync.

Basically, I'm sending new objects from the client app along with a timestamp of the last sync, then fetching anything that changed on the server since the timestamp. I then create the new objects from the client and save the timestamp **after** the new objects are created to exclude them from the next sync.

```
def sync(new_obj_hashes, last_sync)
  updated_items = Item.where(user_id: user_id).where("updated_at > ?", last_sync)

  new_obj_hashes.each |obj_hash|
    Item.new(obj_hash).save!
  end

  last_sync = Time.now
end
```

The problem: From my SQL logs

```
UPDATE "items" SET ...blah blah... WHERE "items"."id" = x
SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."user_id" = y AND (updated_at > z)
```

It's creating the new objects first and **then** fetching the updated objects, which means updated_items (which I send back to the client app) contains all the objects the client sent as well.

How do I get the SELECT statement to happen before the UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updated_items = Item.where(user_id: user_id).where("updated_at > ?", last_sync)
```

doesn't execute a SQL statement. It creates an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which will execute itself when you call a method on it requiring this (for example `all` or most methods from `Enumerable`.

In your case sounds like you want to do

```
updated_items = Item.where(user_id: user_id).where("updated_at > ?", last_sync).all
```

so that the query is evaluated then rather than when you next use `updated_items`